# Drupal Omega 4 - Running bundler to install the necessary gems (Ruby enviromment)

Tags: rubygems, bundler

I am following this guide for setting up Sass on my VM: https://www.drupal.org/node/2138087

- I have a local server, created with Easy PHP.
- The Omega 4 theme is fully functional **within my local server**
- Windows 7

I'm at the following step:

> Running bundler to install the necessary gems
>
> If all went well you now have rvm and the version of ruby required by
>   omega and you can run
>
> bundle install

So I run **bundle install**, but I get this error:

```
$ bundle install
-bash: bundle : command not found
```

Also, when I run **gem install bundle** I get :

```
$ gem install bundle
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (ArgumentError)
    invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
```

Another thing, running the command **ruby -v** in my subTheme gives me :

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p448 (2013-06-27 revision 41675) [i386-cygwin]
```

So all is working pretty fine in there, but I can't get that bundle to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it in a single command line:

```
LANG=C.BINARY gem install bundler
```

It installed bundler and I completed all the next steps :)

Answer (score 0):

To run gem install bundle

First, you have to do a replacement
C:\Ruby21-x64\lib\ruby\2.1.0\win32\registry.rb line 70

Comment the line:

```
#LOCALE = Encoding.find(Encoding.locale_charmap)
```

and add:

```
LOCALE = Encoding::UTF_8
```

Second, adding the the SSL cert:

Donwload http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
and add a sys var on your system :

```
SSL_CERT_FILE : pathtofile/carcert.pem
```

Now you can do a **gem install bundle**